# Crystal Report - formula issue querying two tables with data fields

Tags: sql-server, crystal-reports, report, formula, invoice

right i'm overlysuck with a VAT issue...

I've got a VAT table on my db and a historic VAT with every date the rate has changed on.

Now my issue is - invoices are being raised and the VAT field is coming from the main VAT db which only holds the current VAT rate but if I need to re-print an invoice that was raised before the change of VAT it doesn't take in consideration the date of the invoice...

Now i've tried creating a table with start and end date but that won't be dynamic given the fact it each time VAT changes it would have to be manually changed..

Anyone has any ideas on how could i do this?

```
Invoice    ¦ VAT 
Vat Code ---> Vat Code 

Invoice    ¦   VAT Historic 
Inv Date ---> Vat Date 
Vat Code ---> Vat Code
```

I'm confused as well..!

What I'm using is a formula field with this:

```
IF 
{INVOICE.DATE} in Date({VATHIST.STARTDATE}) to Date({VATHIST.ENDDATE}) 
THEN 
ToText ({VATHIST.RATE}) + "%" 
ELSE 
ToText ({VAT.VATRATE}) + "%"
```

And as I would expect, it doesn't work! 
Dying over here guys! Any help would be immensely appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

what you need to do is to instead of manually adding the start date and end date you add when you add a historic entry into the table.

Also if you really require start date and end date then add those else just insert date which has only date init and shows the date on the particular day.

now your formula will be:

```
IF 
{INVOICE.DATE} in currentdate
THEN 
ToText ({VAT.VATRATE}) + "%" 
ELSE IF {INVOICE.DATE} in Date({VATHIST.STARTDATE}) to Date({VATHIST.ENDDATE}) 
ToText ({VATHIST.RATE}) + "%"
```

Comment: Hi Siva, both VAT tables have 3 entries for a particular code with different dates although on the report I'm getting a blank record for each of the entries which don't fit on the date range. I tried various formulas to supress blank fields but all of them seem to get in the way of running totals of the invoice... Any ideas on how I could get ONLY one line which fit the criteria of the dates and code?

Comment: do you need to manipulate the blank and provide some message?